# Neo4j service not starting

Tags: neo4j

I have been using Neo4j for more than 3 months on this server. Not sure what changed, but today morning I am unable to start Neo4j server.

Till today everything was fine and there were not changes that I know of were made to Neo4j or anything else.
I am currently using neo4j 3.1.0.

The following is the error log.

```
    xxx@dataserver:~$ sudo neo4j console
Starting Neo4j.
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
2017-05-01 03:09:17.948+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-05-01 03:09:18.616+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2017-05-01 03:09:20.766+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2241b683' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2241b683' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2241b683' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:227)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:91)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2241b683' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:443)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:199)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/default.graphdb
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:193)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:57)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@4b1ec7fa' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:415)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:517)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:189)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entry type -1 for version -1. At position LogPosition{logVersion=94, byteOffset=157773910} and entry version V2_1
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryVersion.entryParser(LogEntryVersion.java:141)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader.readLogEntry(VersionAwareLogEntryReader.java:84)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogEntryCursor.next(LogEntryCursor.java:54)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.LatestCheckPointFinder.find(LatestCheckPointFinder.java:78)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.PositionToRecoverFrom.apply(PositionToRecoverFrom.java:53)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI.getPositionToRecoverFrom(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:80)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:80)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:405)
        ... 18 more
```

Comment: This reads like the database log (which is a core part of the database management process, and records the udpates, etc) has become corrupt.  Make sure you back up everything (but don't overwrite an old backup to do that) and check out the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121817/repair-corrupted-neo4j-database-2-3-2-community

Answer (score 0):

Stop service

Change `dbms.allow_upgrade` to `true` in neo4j config file

Start service again

I had the same problem, and upgrading the db fixed it. I would also suggest changing the password if you are still using default password. Once you start the service it should upgrade the database, once upgraded, you can change the dbms.allow_upgrade to false again if you dont want neo4j to update automatically.