# Neo4j fails to read transaction log

Tags: neo4j

We have a neo4j v3.5.14 database running on an Ubuntu server that ran out of disk space. We freed up a lot of the disk space, but after restarting neo4j we are seeing the following error in the log file. It seems like the neo4j service starts up properly (enabled and running), but the database appears to be in an unusable state.  Any suggestions for how to resolve this issue?

```
2022-06-08 15:35:12.975+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
2022-06-08 15:35:14.190+0000 WARN [o.n.k.r.LogTailScanner] Fail to read transaction log version 1. Transaction logs contains entries with prefix 0, and the lowest supported prefix is 5. This indicates that the log files originates from an older version of neo4j, which we don't support migrations from.. At position LogPosition{logVersion=1, byteOffset=126140484} and entry version null
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.UnsupportedLogVersionException: Transaction logs contains entries with prefix 0, and the lowest supported prefix is 5. This indicates that the log files originates from an older version of neo4j, which we don't support migrations from.. At position LogPosition{logVersion=1, byteOffset=126140484} and entry version null
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryVersion.byVersion(LogEntryVersion.java:169)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader.readLogEntry(VersionAwareLogEntryReader.java:80)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogEntryCursor.next(LogEntryCursor.java:54)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.LogTailScanner.findLogTail(LogTailScanner.java:99)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.LogTailScanner.getTailInformation(LogTailScanner.java:260)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogVersionUpgradeChecker.check(LogVersionUpgradeChecker.java:48)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:349)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:116)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:227)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:148)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityGraphFactory.newGraphDatabase(CommunityGraphFactory.java:41)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:180)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:91)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
2022-06-08 15:35:14.192+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2022-06-08 15:35:14.192+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2022-06-08 15:35:14.192+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer on the following post resolved my issue.  The suggested fix was successfully tested in a copy I created of the database I was having problems with.  I also made a backup of my original problem database.  After successful testing in the copy, the fix was applied to the original database and everything is working great.  [Repair corrupted neo4j database (2.3.2 community)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121817/repair-corrupted-neo4j-database-2-3-2-community/35126072#35126072)